# How to set plain header in docx file using apache poi?

Tags: java, header, apache-poi, docx

I would like to create a header for docx document using apache poi but I have difficulties. I have no working code to show. I would like to ask for some piece of code as starting point.

Comment: Does you file already have a header (possibly blank) that you want to change, or is it a brand new file without any headers yet?

Comment: It is blank file that I am generating within poi API. I just want to add some header.

Comment: Can you call [document.getHeaderFooterPolicy()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getHeaderFooterPolicy()) and then get the header to manipulate from that, creating a new one if needed?

Comment: Yes, I can call document.getHeaderFooterPolicy() but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Does your document already have any headers set on it?

Comment: No. The document doesn't have any header.

Comment: No HeaderFooterPolicy, or no even/odd/first headers?

Comment: Absolutely none of these.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [Apache POI Unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFHeader.java) that covers your very case - you're looking for [TestXWPFHeader#testSetHeader()](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFHeader.java). It covers starting with a document with no headers or footers set, then adding them

Your code would basically be something like:

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = sampleDoc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
if (policy.getDefaultHeader() == null && policy.getFirstPageHeader() == null
       && policy.getDefaultFooter() == null) {
   // Need to create some new headers
   // The easy way, gives a single empty paragraph
   XWPFHeader headerD = policy.createHeader(policy.DEFAULT);
   headerD.getParagraphs(0).createRun().setText("Hello Header World!");

   // Or the full control way
    CTP ctP1 = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
    CTR ctR1 = ctP1.addNewR();
    CTText t = ctR1.addNewT();
    t.setStringValue("Paragraph in header");

    XWPFParagraph p1 = new XWPFParagraph(ctP1, sampleDoc);
    XWPFParagraph[] pars = new XWPFParagraph[1];
    pars[0] = p1;

    policy.createHeader(policy.FIRST, pars);
} else {
   // Already has a header, change it
}
```

See the [XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy JavaDocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.html) for a bit more on creating headers and footers.

It isn't the nicest, so it could ideally use some kind soul submitting a patch to make it nicer (hint hint...!), but it can work as the unit tests show

Comment: policy in line `XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = sampleDoc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();` is null already. And basically this is the problem for most of us. How do we get a non-NULL policy out of a document?

Comment: If you document has no header footer policy, which would be unusual, then you'd need to create an empty one first. You'd need to ask that as a new question though, as that's a different problem to the OP's one

Comment: I am creating a document from scratch. I have set all my paragraphs and saved it to a docx. I'm opening the file anew to add header/footer to it. No matter what I do, my policy is always NULL.

Comment: How exactly are you doing it? Do you save the file and reopen it?

Comment: I'm starting from an existing document, as you can see from the code code I linked to! If you want to start with a brand new document, that's a different question...

Comment: Is it possible to edit/replace the header text/image?
if possible, please post the solution..

policy.getDefaultHeader().getText() gives header text, but policy.getDefaultHeader().getParagraphs().get(0).getText() is empty....

Comment: Its not working for  Landscape mode. any solution @Gagravarr

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer, just copy and paste:

```
public void test1() throws IOException{

    XWPFDocument sampleDoc = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = sampleDoc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
    //in an empty document always will be null
    if(policy==null){
        CTSectPr sectPr = sampleDoc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        policy = new  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy( sampleDoc, sectPr );
    }

    if (policy.getDefaultHeader() == null && policy.getFirstPageHeader() == null
            && policy.getDefaultFooter() == null) {
        XWPFHeader headerD = policy.createHeader(policy.DEFAULT);
        headerD.getParagraphs().get(0).createRun().setText("Hello Header World!");


    } 
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.currentTimeMillis()+"_test1_header.docx");
    sampleDoc.write(out);
    out.close();
    sampleDoc.close();
}
```